# CakePHP friendly seo url

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, friendly-url

I want to make my url seo friendly. `www.example.com/posts/view/1` change for `www.example.pl/:slug-:id`. Everything works fine, but probably I'm doing something wrong with routing, because when after clicking the urls in paginator, the url is correct, it looks like `www.example.pl/:slug-:id` , but it appears an error

`"The requested address 'www.example.pl/:slug-:id' was not found on this server."`

I don't know what's wrong. Here's my code:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:slug-:id',
    array(
        'controller' => 'posts', 
        'action' => 'view'
    ),
    array(
        'pass' => array('slug' , 'id'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
    )
);
```

in paginator view:

```
echo $this->Html->link($ad['Post']['title'], array(
    'controller' => 'posts',
    'action' => 'view',
    'slug' => Inflector::slug($post['Post']['title'],'-'),
    'id'=>$post['Post']['id'])
);
```

I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. In the posts controller my view function was wrong. Here's right correct:

```
function view($id = null, $slug = null) {
$this->Post->id = $this->params['post'];
$this->set('post', $this->Post->read());
```

Comment: +1 for answering your own question. Note that the code was not wrong,  it just didn't match the route definition.

Answer (score 4):

Its too simple i'll give you an example from my project .. 
in your **routes.php**

```
Router::connect(
    '/:slug-:id',
    array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view'),
    array('pass'=>array('slug','id'),'slug'=>'[a-zA-Z0-9 -]+','id'=>'[0-9]+')
);
```

your link in **views** should be like .

```
$this->Html->link(__('link desu'),array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view','id'=>$post['Post']['id'],'slug'=>$post['Post']['slug']));
```

and your **PostsController.php**

```
public function view($slug,$id){
    $this->Post->id = $id;
    // ....
}
```

Quick tip : try to create an array in your PostModel to avoid creating it every time in your view .
example :

**Post.php**

```
class Post extends AppModel{
    // ....
        public function afterFind($results,$primary = false){
        foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
            if(isset($value[$this->alias]['id'])){
                $results[$key][$this->alias]['url'] = array(
                                 'controller'=>'posts',
                                 'action'=>'view',
                                 'id'=>$results[$key][$this->alias]['id'],
                                 'slug'=>$results[$key][$this->alias]['slug']
                            );  
            }
            // ....
        }
        return $results;
    }
}
```

}

so you can call it in your view simply like that

```
$this->Html->link(__('link desu'),$post['Post']['url']);
```

Comment: +1 though the "quick tip" is a distraction from the actual answer.

Comment: how come , its just to avoid creating those big arrays(sometimes) everytime u want to get your Url

Comment: Remember you're answering a question: Over half your answer is not related to the question - Now knowing the problem (see author's answer) the only line (singlular, 1) that actually fixes the problem is this: `public function view($slug,$id){`.

Comment: i see . just wanna give a bonus to my answer with that useful tip , thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a problem with the regex on the route. Your slug contain hyphens `-` which you also use to separate between the slug and the id. i.e.:

```
example.com/my-slug-has-hyphens-1
```

The regex is not smart enough to know that the "last" hyphen separates the slug from the id.

To test if this is the problem, try using a route like this `'/:slug__:id',` just to see if it works.

Comment: It's a reasonable guess but that's not how a greedy regex works - with no restriction the slug would simply be the string 'my-slug-has-hyphens'. I recommend trying what you're suggesting _before_ answering.

Answer (score 0):

### Pass is order sensitive

In the question the route is as follows:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:slug-:id',
    array(
        'controller' => 'posts', 
        'action' => 'view'
    ),
    array(
        'pass' => array('slug' , 'id'), # <-
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
    )
);
```

That means the post function will recieve:

```
public function view($slug, $id)
```

As indicated by the edited question, the code is expecting the id to be the first parameter. The easiest solution is simply to specify the passed parameters in the order that they are expected:

```
...
        'pass' => array('id', 'slug'), # <-
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Router::connect(
    '/:slug/:id',
    array(
        'controller' => 'posts', 
        'action' => 'view'
    ),
    array(
        'pass' => array('slug' , 'id'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
    )
);
```

the above code will create correct link as www.example.com/posts/view/title/1

```
echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'], array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', Inflector::slug($post['Post']['title'],'-'),$post['Post']['id']));
```

Comment: -1 as this changes the question to match the answer - it _doesn't answer the question_.